# Text fragment reconstruction using regex - Java

Tags: java, regex

Problem Statement:

Imagine you have several copies of the same page of text. Someone rips each page up into fragments. Write a program to reassemble a given set of text fragments into their original sequence. The program should have a main method accepting the path to a text file containing text fragments separated by a semicolon. Each line in the file is a different test case.

As it stands I have created a basic nested loop system to iterate over the file and output the reassembled "pages".

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Imagine you have several copies of the same page of text. Someone rips each
 * page up into fragments. Write a program to reassemble a given set of text
 * fragments into their original sequence. The program should have a main method
 * accepting the path to a text file containing text fragments separated by a
 * semicolon. Each line in the file is a different test case.
 * 
 * 
 */
public class Defragmenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pages2.txt"));
            String fragmentProblem;
            while ((fragmentProblem = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(reassemble(fragmentProblem));
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assemble the fragments in the correct order.
     * 
     * @param line
     *            String containing the fragments of the document.
     * @return the line in the correct order.
     */
    private static String reassemble(String fragmentProblem) {

        // Each line contains text fragments separated by a semicolon.
        String[] fragments = fragmentProblem.split(";");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fragments));

        // Sort the fragments by size
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o2.length() - o1.length();
            }
        });

        // Pick up the first fragment
        String text = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);

        // Start the algorithm
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int max = 0;
            int idx = 0;
            int match = 0;
            int trueLength = 0;
            int findMeLength= 0;
            for (int j = list.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                String findMe = list.get(j);
                trueLength = text.length();
                findMeLength= findMe.length();
                for (int lookBack = 1 - findMe.length(); lookBack < text.length(); lookBack++) {
                    if (lookBack < 0) { // Prefix
                        int length = findMeLength + lookBack;
                        if (text.regionMatches(0, findMe, -lookBack, length)) {
                            if (length > max) {
                                idx = lookBack;
                                max = length;
                                match = j;
                            }
                        }
                    } else { // Suffix
                        int length = lookBack + findMeLength<= trueLength ? findMeLength: trueLength - lookBack;
                        if (text.regionMatches(lookBack, findMe, 0, length)) {
                            if (length > max) {
                                idx = lookBack;
                                max = length;
                                match = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (idx < 0) { // Prefix
                text = list.get(match).substring(0, -idx) + text;
            } else if (idx > trueLength - list.get(match).length()) { // Suffix
                text = text + list.get(match).substring(trueLength - idx);
            }
            list.remove(match);
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

What I am looking to do is something similar using the regular expression "regex" system in java. I just wanted some feedback at how to approach this problem

Comment: An advice for your future work, stop using variables as `n`, `m`, `xx`,`ffs` etc... That will cost you a lot...

Comment: good point ill sort that out now

Comment: should be easier to understand now